# How to do authentication with a site and two reusable web services with Open ID Connect and Azure AD?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, architecture, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I am building a system with an ASP.NET Core web app (incidentally, in Blazor), which let's call "Site", and some domain web services (which might someday be used by other sites), one of which let's call "CustomerService".

Following various guides and articles on how to set up authentication with Open ID Connect and Azure Active Directory for this system, I see the following possible different approaches to authentication and authorization, especially with regard to AJAX requests:

1. **Site-only auth, passthrough**: Service trusts the site; site authenticates user.
2. **Service-only auth, passthrough**: Service authenticates user; site passes through all AJAX requests.
3. **Service-only auth, CORS** Service provides site client data via CORS, with authentication; site doesn't handle AJAX requests at all.
4. **Service and site auth, passthrough**: Service and site both authenticate user; site passes through some AJAX requests.

These all seem to have significant practical problems.  **Is there a fifth approach, or a variation I should be considering?**

Here's my elaboration of these approaches.

(1) **Service trusts the site; site authenticates user**:

(1a) Set up Site.Server to use Open ID Connect for users to authenticate, implement all necessary authorization on Site.Server, pass through web API calls to CustomerService, and set up CustomerService to trust requests that come from Site.Server.  This looks like a bad idea because then any user can spoof Site.Server and have full access to operations that should be secured on CustomerService.  Also, CustomerService would not be able to enforce authorization; we'd be trusting Site.Server to get it right, which seems suboptimal.

(1b) Same as (1a), but Site.Server would know a secret API key that would be passed to CustomerService, either in headers or the API call's querystring or body.  This doesn't seem so great because the API key would never change and then could be discovered and spoofed by any user.  Still, this could work, as the API key could stay secret, and we could use our secret server for both sides to retrieve it.  But still CustomerService would not be able to enforce authorization; we'd be trusting Site.Server to get it right, which seems suboptimal.

(1c) Same as (1b), but we come up with a mechanism for rotating the API key occasionally.  This doesn't seem so great because the API key would change and then could be discovered and spoofed by any user.  Still, this could work, as the API key could stay secret, and we could use our secret server for both sides to retrieve it.  But still CustomerService would not be able to enforce authorization; we'd be trusting Site.Server to get it right, which seems suboptimal.

(2) **Service authenticates user; site passes through all AJAX requests**:  Avoid any authentication on Site.Server and instead enforce authorization/authentication on CustomerService only through Open ID Connect+Azure AD.  Site.Server would have to pass through requests including headers to CustomerService.  This has the benefit of putting the security in the right place, but it seems unworkable, as the user has no way to authenticate on CustomerService since the user isn't using CustomerService directly; their AJAX requests still go to Site.Server.

(3) **Service provides site client data via CORS, with authentication; site doesn't handle AJAX requests at all**:  Avoid any authentication on Site.Server and instead use CORS to allow the user's browser to connect directly to CustomerService, requiring authentication only through Open ID Connect+Azure AD.  This has the benefit of putting the security in the right place, but how can a user authenticate on a AJAX request without having done so in a human-browsable way first?  My AJAX request can't redirect to microsoftonline and prompt the user, can it?  Plus CORS seems like a bad idea in general--we want to move away from cross-site anything; to the user, it should appear that Site.Server is serving up both AJAX calls and HTML page requests, right?

(4) **Service and site both authenticate user; site passes through some AJAX requests.** Put authentication on both Site.Server and CustomerService, with the same app ID, making them appear as one and the same site as far as Azure AD knows.  Site.Server could do its own authentication and restrict certain service calls from getting to CustomerService, or it could pass through requests, including headers, to CustomerService, which could then deny or grant access as well.  This is what we decided to do, but I question it now, as if I add a
second service, now it has to have again the same app ID to keep this approach.

None of these approaches seem to hit the mark. Am I missing another approach that I should be considering?  Or is there a variation I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Here are my thoughts on what an option 5 is:

**WEB UI**

Code runs in the browser and interacts with the Authorization Server to authenticate the user. A library such as [OIDC Client](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) does the security work for you.

Provides best usability and simplest code. The UI uses access tokens to call cross domain APIs. Renewing tokens is tricky though, and browser security requires some due diligence.

**WEB BACK END**

Is static content only, deployed around the world close to end users - perhaps via Azure CDN. Must execute zero code. Provides best performance.

**WEB UI SAME AS MOBILE UI**

Your Web UI in effect operates in an identical manner to a mobile UI and is quite a bit simpler, with less need for cookies + double hops.

**ENTRY POINT API**

The browser UI interacts with an entry point API tailored to UI consumers. This API validates tokens by downloading Azure AD token signing keys. It is also has first say in authorizing requests.

The entry point API orchestrates calls to Core APIs and Azure APIs such as Graph. The Web UI uses a single token scoped to the entry point API and you can strictly control the UI's privileges. Meanwhile the API can use Azure AD's 'on behalf of' feature to get tokens for downstream APIs so that the UI does not need to deal with this.

**DOMAIN APIs**

These typically run in a locked down private cloud and are not called directly by the outside world. This allows you closer control over which types of caller can invoke which high privilege operations.

**BLOG POSTS OF MINE**

My blog's [index page](https://authguidance.com/home/mainindex/) has further info on these patterns and the goals behind them. Maybe have a browse of the SPA Goals and API Platform Architecture posts.

There are some working code samples on [this page](https://authguidance.com/home/code-samples-quickstart/). In my case the hosting uses AWS instead of Azure, though concepts are the same.

Comment: So the entry point API "validates tokens" that the Web UI provides?  This is not user authentication, then, but tokens that are requested by the Web UI for this purpose?  That is, they are not specific to the user of the web UI?

Comment: The Web UI tokens have a subject claim to identify the end user. Some messages + token details [here](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/) in case it helps. The Web UI is getting a token on behalf of the end user - not itself.

Comment: I see.  So that end user's browser is making AJAX requests from the entry point api via CORS?

Comment: Yep - browser calls entry point APIs directly and CORS is involved. Tend to fit best with cloud hosting, which often uses different domains or subdomains for Web and API.